# How to make an two capturing groups inside a optional non capturing group.

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

So I have this regex that is an approximation of what I want:

```
^#!addr0=(.*?)(?=\/addr1=)\/addr1=(.*)\/coord0=(.*)\/coord1=(.*)
```

When I pass this string:

```
#!addr0=one/addr1=two/coord0=three/coord1=four
```

It captures: `one`, `two`, `three` and `four` correctly, see [here](http://regex101.com/r/wC0dX4).

The problem is I want to be able to capture the following string:

```
#!addr0=one/addr1=two
```

This should capture: `one` and `two`.

And optionally the string can also contain (though I can guarantee that `addr0=` and `addr1=` will be there):

```
/coord0=three/coord1=four
```

So as far as I understand I would need an optional non capturing group, so I though of this:

```
^#!addr0=(.*?)(?=\/addr1=)\/addr1=(.*)(?:\/coord0=(.*)\/coord1=(.*))?
```

This doesn't work because the groups are: `one` and `two/coord0=three/coord1=four`.

([see it here](http://regex101.com/r/sE3eS8))

This I guess is quite close because when I don't put the question mark at the end I get: `one`, `two`, `three` and `four` but the string with only `addr0=` and `addr1=` does not match ([here](http://regex101.com/r/oH1bQ4)).

Comment: maybe checking for non-slashes? `^#!addr0=(.*?)(?=\/addr1=)\/addr1=([^/]*)(?:\/coord0=([^/]*)\/coord1=([^/]*))?`

Comment: @user887675 The problem there would be that I can't really have an address with a slash on the second address...

Comment: FYI, added explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking for this:

```
^#!addr0=(.*?)\/addr1=([^/]*)(?:\/coord0=(.*)\/coord1=(.*))?
```

In the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qH1iC9), see the capture groups in the bottom right pane.

1. One issue with your original is that the lookahead `(?=\/addr1=)` was redundant, since you always match `/address1`
2. For Group 2, instead of the lazy greedy `.*?`, we use the negated character class `[^/]*`. Why? Because since the final part is optional, the lazy `.*?` would be allowed to give up too early.
3. The final part is entered into a non-capturing group `(?:` and made optional.